# How to read properties file from meta-inf folder from a POJO

Tags: java, jar, properties, package, meta-inf

How to read properties file from meta-inf folder in a web application from plain java class.

Comment: Please include the code you have tried. Please also include any errors you get.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest you can do is :-

```
InputStream propertiesIs = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/your.properties");
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(propertiesIs);
System.out.println(prop.getProperty(YourPropertyHere));
```

OR

you can try loading your properties using `FileInputStream` also :-

```
input = new FileInputStream("META-INF/your.properties");
```

Comment: @sahoo1989 that's why we should give what we have tried so far in the question description itself & the current code / structure

Comment: there's a missing `/`.  at least for me, that seems required.

Answer (score 1):

```
package net.bounceme.doge.json;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class PropertiesReader {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PropertiesReader.class.getName());

    public Properties tryGetProps(String propertiesFileName) {
        log.fine(propertiesFileName);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties = getProps(propertiesFileName);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PropertiesReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        log.info(properties.toString());
        return properties;
    }

    private Properties getProps(String propertiesFileName) throws IOException {
        log.fine(propertiesFileName);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(PropertiesReader.class.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/" + propertiesFileName + ".properties"));
        log.fine(properties.toString());
        return properties;
    }
}
```

this [works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45758528/262852) for me.

Answer (score 1):

When reading resources, one should take care of closing them properly.

```
    InputStream streamOrNull = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
            "META-INF/your.properties");
    if (streamOrNull == null) {
        // handle no such file
    }
    else {
        try (InputStream stream = streamOrNull) { // close stream eventually
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(stream);
            // access properties
        }
    }
```