# how to load a properties file from the META-INF directory?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, jar, meta-inf

Is it correct to say that `properties` files used in execution by a running `JAR` best belong in `META-INF`?  The notion being to fit with the Standard Directory Layout [specified](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) by `Maven`.

Assuming that structure is desired, how is the `properties` file loaded from `META-INF`?

```
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/json_parser$ 
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/json_parser$ java -jar build/libs/json_parser-all.jarAug 18, 2017 6:44:24 AM net.bounceme.doge.json.Main main
INFO: starting
Aug 18, 2017 6:44:24 AM net.bounceme.doge.json.Main run
INFO: actually
Aug 18, 2017 6:44:24 AM net.bounceme.doge.json.PropertiesReader tryGetProps
INFO: properties
Aug 18, 2017 6:44:24 AM net.bounceme.doge.json.PropertiesReader getProps
INFO: properties
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
    at net.bounceme.doge.json.PropertiesReader.getProps(PropertiesReader.java:26)
    at net.bounceme.doge.json.PropertiesReader.tryGetProps(PropertiesReader.java:16)
    at net.bounceme.doge.json.Main.run(Main.java:18)
    at net.bounceme.doge.json.Main.main(Main.java:12)
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/json_parser$ 
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/json_parser$ jar tf build/libs/json_parser-all.jarMETA-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/javax.json/
META-INF/maven/javax.json/javax.json-api/
META-INF/maven/javax.json/javax.json-api/pom.properties
META-INF/maven/javax.json/javax.json-api/pom.xml
javax/
javax/json/
javax/json/Json.class
javax/json/JsonArray.class
javax/json/JsonArrayBuilder.class
javax/json/JsonBuilderFactory.class
javax/json/JsonException.class
javax/json/JsonMergePatch.class
javax/json/JsonNumber.class
javax/json/JsonObject.class
javax/json/JsonObjectBuilder.class
javax/json/JsonPatch$Operation.class
javax/json/JsonPatch.class
javax/json/JsonPatchBuilder.class
javax/json/JsonPointer.class
javax/json/JsonReader.class
javax/json/JsonReaderFactory.class
javax/json/JsonString.class
javax/json/JsonStructure.class
javax/json/JsonValue$ValueType.class
javax/json/JsonValue.class
javax/json/JsonValueImpl.class
javax/json/JsonWriter.class
javax/json/JsonWriterFactory.class
javax/json/spi/
javax/json/spi/JsonProvider.class
javax/json/stream/
javax/json/stream/JsonCollectors.class
javax/json/stream/JsonGenerationException.class
javax/json/stream/JsonGenerator.class
javax/json/stream/JsonGeneratorFactory.class
javax/json/stream/JsonLocation.class
javax/json/stream/JsonParser$Event.class
javax/json/stream/JsonParser.class
javax/json/stream/JsonParserFactory.class
javax/json/stream/JsonParsingException.class
module-info.class
net/
net/bounceme/
net/bounceme/doge/
net/bounceme/doge/json/
net/bounceme/doge/json/Main.class
net/bounceme/doge/json/Marshaller.class
net/bounceme/doge/json/PropertiesReader.class
net/bounceme/doge/json/JsonReader.class
json.json
properties.properties
META-INF/properties.properties
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/json_parser$ 
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/json_parser$ jar tf build/libs/json_parser-all.jar | grep properties.properties
properties.properties
META-INF/properties.properties
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/json_parser$
```

and the relevant code:

```
package net.bounceme.doge.json;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class PropertiesReader {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PropertiesReader.class.getName());

    public Properties tryGetProps(String propertiesFileName) {
        log.info(propertiesFileName);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties = getProps(propertiesFileName);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PropertiesReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return properties;
    }

    private Properties getProps(String propertiesFileName) throws IOException {
        log.info(propertiesFileName);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(PropertiesReader.class.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/" + propertiesFileName));
        log.info(properties.toString());
        return properties;
    }
}
```

This is in [relation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45756775/262852) to using `init` properly from gradle and based on [general](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6683375/262852) information.

I tried removing the leading `/` as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31316490/262852) -- same result as above.

Comment: "Is it correct to say that properties files used in execution by a running JAR best belong in META-INF?". I would say no. IMHO `META-INF` should rather contains information about the JAR itself (hence the pom.properties and pom.xml Maven puts in), so that frameworks/app servers will better know how to handle this (think about the MANIFEST.MF for OSGi, the META-INF/ejb-jar.xml...). That said, it is just another package, so loading a properties file should work the same way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not obliged to store your properties files in META-INF, indeed it's not even very common to do so (in my experience at least). In support of this contention the [Java JAR Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#The_META-INF_directory) doesn't include properties files amongst the expected contents of META-INF.

The code below shows several approach to loading properties from a JAR, whether they are in META-INF or not.

Given a JAR file with this content:

```
jar -tvf properties.jar
   0 Fri Aug 18 15:35:52 IST 2017 META-INF/
  68 Fri Aug 18 15:35:52 IST 2017 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
   4 Fri Aug 18 15:35:32 IST 2017 META-INF/bProps.properties
   4 Fri Aug 18 15:35:18 IST 2017 aProps.properties
```

You can load `aProps.properties` and `bProps.properties` like so:

```
@Test
public void canWriteAndRead() throws IOException {
    ClassLoader systemClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    // this works
    loadProperties(systemClassLoader.getResource("aProps.properties"));
    // this works
    loadProperties(systemClassLoader.getResource("META-INF/bProps.properties"));
    // this does not work
    loadProperties(systemClassLoader.getResource("/aProps.properties"));
    // this does not work
    loadProperties(systemClassLoader.getResource("/META-INF/bProps.properties"));

    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    // this works
    loadProperties(classLoader.getResource("aProps.properties"));
    // this works
    loadProperties(classLoader.getResource("META-INF/bProps.properties"));
    // this does not work
    loadProperties(classLoader.getResource("/aProps.properties"));
    // this does not work
    loadProperties(classLoader.getResource("/META-INF/bProps.properties"));

    // this works
    loadProperties(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/aProps.properties"));
    // this works
    loadProperties(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/bProps.properties"));
    // this does not work
    loadProperties(getClass().getResourceAsStream("aProps.properties"));
    // this does not work
    loadProperties(getClass().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/bProps.properties"));
}

private void loadProperties(InputStream incoming) throws IOException {
    if (incoming != null) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(incoming);
        for (String s : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}

private void loadProperties(URL incoming) throws IOException {
    if (incoming != null) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(incoming.openStream());
        for (String s : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: TL;DR.  No, I will, thanks for digging up the official docs.  Still wonder why Maven has that convention.  Maybe it's more geared towards WAR files, but they've generalized it for some reason.  I thought it seemed odd.  (I had a slight error with my attempt:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45759697/262852 so that's fixed, incidentally.)